# Determining the probability of having over a dollar amount based on defined bills.

Tags: probability

Good day,

I am having difficulty solving the following problem from a leisure math activity:

#### Problem

> [] has a money bag containing a \$20 bill, two \$10 bills, two \$5 bills, and a \$1 bill. If he randomly draws out three bills, what is the probability that the sum of the bills is greater than $25?

#### Answer Choices

The possible answer choices are 25%, 40%, 44%, 50%, & 61%. The answer key included states that the correct answer is 50%, but I do not understand why.

#### What I know

I know the total number of permutations of bill combinations is 6!, and I believe that it is reduced to 6!/3! due to the three-bill draw. I attempted to write out the possible permutations over $25 by hand, but I know there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bills have been carefully chosen so having more than $\$25$ is equivalent to having the $\$20$ bill.  If you do have the $\$20$, the least you can have is $20+5+1=26$.  If you don't have the $\$20$, the most you can have is $10+10+5=25$.  You draw three bills out of six, so the chance you get the $\$20$ is $50\%$.

Comment: Haha, this is why I love math :). Makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest is to observe that the only way the person does not fetch greater than a sum of $25$ dollars in three draws is that he/she does not fetch $20$ dollar bill in any of the draws. In other words, the person draws from remaining $5$ bills.

The probability of that is ${5 \choose 3} / {6 \choose 3} = 1/2$

So subtracting from $1$, you get to $50\%$ probability that the person fetches a sum of more than $25$ dollars in three draws.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response :). I understood Ross's response more so I selected him as the answer but I am very appreciative of your answer :).

Comment: :) yes you should choose Ross's answer as it is a step simpler after the same observation we both made. But you can always ask for clarification if anything is not clear in my answer.